# Implicit conversion and map key

Tags: scala, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I've defined an enum

```
object SupportedCurrencies extends Enumeration {
  type SupportedCurrencies = Value

  val USD, GBP, ARS, AUD, BRL, CAD, CHF, CNY, EUR, JPY, SEK, DKK, NOK = Value
}
```

and implicit conversion for it to string

```
implicit def supportedCurrencyToString(currency: SupportedCurrencies.Value): String = currency.toString
```

but if I'll try to create a Map[String, Int]

```
val m: Map[String, Int] = Map(USD -> 1)
```

I'm getting an error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (helpers.SupportedCurrencies.Value, Int)
[error]  required: (String, Int)
[error]         val m: Map[String, Int] = Map(USD -> 1)
```

Could anyone explain what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked closely at the error and get it

```
implicit def supportedCurrencyToString(currencyEntry: (helpers.SupportedCurrencies.Value, Int)): (String, Int) = currencyEntry._1.toString -> currencyEntry._2
```

I was needed conversion from pair to pair